# How to Implement "Multidirectional" LSTMs?

Tags: deep-learning, keras, lstm

I'm trying to implement this LSTM Architecture from the paper "Dropout improves Recurrent Neural Networks for Handwriting Recognition": [image: Architecture from the paper Dropout improves Recurrent Neural Networks for Handwriting Recognition]

In the paper, the researchers defined Multidirectional LSTM Layers as "Four LSTM layers applied in parallel, each with a **particular scanning direction**"

Here's how (I think) the network looks like in Keras:

```
from keras.layers import LSTM, Dropout, Input, Convolution2D, Merge, Dense, Activation, TimeDistributed
from keras.models import Sequential

def build_lstm_dropout(inputdim, outputdim, return_sequences=True, activation='tanh'):
    net_input = Input(shape=(None, inputdim))
    model = Sequential()
    lstm  = LSTM(output_dim=outputdim, return_sequences=return_sequences, activation=activation)(net_input)
    model.add(lstm)
    model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    return model

def build_conv(nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, net_input, border_mode='relu'):
    return TimeDistributed(Convolution2D( nb_filter, nb_row, nb_col, border_mode=border_mode, activation='relu')(net_input))

def build_lstm_conv(lstm, conv):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(lstm)
    model.add(conv)
    return model

def build_merged_lstm_conv_layer(lstm_conv, mode='concat'):
    return Merge([lstm_conv, lstm_conv, lstm_conv, lstm_conv], mode=mode)

def build_model(feature_dim, loss='ctc_cost_for_train', optimizer='Adadelta'):
    net_input = Input(shape=(1, feature_dim, None))

    lstm = build_lstm_dropout(2, 6)
    conv = build_conv(64, 2, 4, net_input)

    lstm_conv = build_lstm_conv(lstm, conv)

    first_layer = build_merged_lstm_conv_layer(lstm_conv)

    lstm = build_lstm_dropout(10, 20)
    conv = build_conv(128, 2, 4, net_input)

    lstm_conv = build_lstm_conv(lstm, conv)

    second_layer = build_merged_lstm_conv_layer(lstm_conv)

    lstm = build_lstm_dropout(50, 1)
    fully_connected = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')

    lstm_fc = Sequential()
    lstm_fc.add(lstm)
    lstm_fc.add(fully_connected)

    third_layer = Merge([lstm_fc, lstm_fc, lstm_fc, lstm_fc], mode='concat')

    final_model = Sequential()
    final_model.add(first_layer)
    final_model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    final_model.add(second_layer)
    final_model.add(Activation('tanh'))
    final_model.add(third_layer)

    final_model.compile(loss=loss, optimizer=optimizer, sample_weight_mode='temporal')

    return final_model
```

And here are my questions:

1. If my implementation of the architecture is correct, how do you
   implement the scanning directions for the four LSTM layers?
2. If my implementation is not correct, is it possible to implement
   such an architecture in Keras? If not, are there any other frameworks that can help me in implementing such an architecture?

Comment: What did "particular scanning direction" mean? Did you mean that it looks like "Bidirectional RNN" but on 2d grids?

Comment: Yup. Got it from this paper: Offline Handwriting Recognition with
Multidimensional Recurrent Neural Networks

Comment: Are you sure that it is "Multi Directional"?
Because as far as I know MDLSTM stands for "Multi Dimentional LSTM"

Answer (score 2):

You can check [this](https://github.com/fchollet/keras/issues/1629) for the implementation of bidirectional LSTM. Basically, you just set `go_backwards=True` for the backward-LSTM.

However, in your case, you have to write a "mirror"+reshape layer to reverse the rows. A mirror layer can look like (I am using lambda layer here for convenience) : `Lambda(lambda x: x[:,::-1,:])`

Comment: Alright, I'll try this one. I'll get back to you when I get results.

Comment: Do you get any result? I'm still wondering how to implement MDLSTM for text recognition, do you have any reference?